# How to get rid or ignore NaNs? error float when using split

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, split

In the y column I have words but in some rows there are NaNs so it shows me an error that I can't use split on float because of the nans.

What to change?

Column y looks like text1,text2,nun, nun,text3

```
missing_values = ["#N/A","None","nan"]
df_eval = pd.read_csv('e.csv',na_values = missing_values)

with open('e1.csv', 'a', newline='',errors='ignore', encoding="utf8" ) as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        #df_eval= pd.read_csv(f,na_values = missing_values)
# Importing the dataset

        for j in range(len(df_eval)):
           x=df_eval.iloc[j,1]
           #print("X", x)
#             x1=x.split("|")
# #           print(x1)
           y=df_eval.iloc[j,2]
           #df_new = df[df_eval.iloc[j,2]].notnull()]
            
           if str(y=="nan"):
               continue
           print("y", y)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean nan?

Comment: yes. how to do split with nans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the case when x is nan separately, you could either skip the loop using continue as shown below. or set x to be an empty string x = '' if you think that is more appropriate.

```
...
for j in range(len(df_eval)):
    x=df_eval.iloc[j,1]
    if pd.isna(x):
       continue; 
    ...
 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just want something like this:

```py
from math import isnan

for row in df.iterrows():
    entries = [x for x in row[1] if not isnan(x)]
    do_stuff(entries)
```

in other words, since you're iterating anyhow, you might as well just build a standard python type (list) containing the variables you want, and then work with that.

The basic approach---check whether something `isnan()` or not is more widely applicable.

Note that you can't use `.split()` on a float, whether it's `nan` or not.